# iOS 4.3: How to handle the logging message: "Received memory warning. Level=1"?

Tags: ios, memory, warnings

I have created a little app for my iPhone. When I run it on my device the output console sometimes logs the message

> Received memory warning. Level=1
>   Memory-Warnung

Well, I guess this might be perhaps due to some unreleased memory, but I'm not sure about that. So my question is: Is there a possibilty to track down where this message comes from?

Are there tools to analyze my program so that I can find out why this message is displayed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Instruments (Product menu -> Profile) and test for Leaks. If leaks are detected, get rid of them, see if you get more memory warnings. If yes, test Allocations, see what's using memory the most and try to optimize memory usage.